# Styling bootstrap rows & columns html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm trying to style this html file so that I have a panel on the side (Members), and pictures on the right of that, lined up in rows of three. My questions are:

1. How do I make it so that the bootstrap columns containing the images are actually to the right of the bootstrap panel?
2. There is some space between the rows of the images?

Below is my code and how it appears on my browser:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Members</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Faculty</h3>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Students</h3>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Alumni</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
      <!-- vvvvvvvvvvvvvv-FACE OF THE ORG-vvvvvvvvvvvvvv -->
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/left2.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/right.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/right1.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/left2.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/right.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img class="image-rounded" src="img/right1.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

     </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Thank you for any and all help! :)

Comment: Wait.. Do you have problem with styling your page or sending data to database with php?

Comment: Woops, that title was saved from a previous post! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Members</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Faculty</h3>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Students</h3>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Alumni</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- vvvvvvvvvvvvvv-FACE OF THE ORG-vvvvvvvvvvvvvv -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/left2.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/right.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/right1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/left2.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/right.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="img/right1.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

     </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

try this code.I edit the code. 
and img-rounded css give padding or margin for space.

Comment: Yes!! THANK YOU! :D so you just have to close the container div before adding the image column and rows?